# Using tailwindcss in custom angular library

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I am using Angular 12 to create a custom library. In this library I want to use tailwindcss to style my custom component. I declared tailwindcss an a peer dependency and created the tailwinscss.config.js file in the root of the library folder and imported all necessary modules into the scss file of the component. Unfortunately tailwind classes are not loaded.

Then I noted that if my application where I import my library into also uses tailwind and uses any class that is also used in the library, the custom component is styled correctly.

For example: my custom component has class `bg-green-800`. When I load this component in my app, it does not apply the background color. Then I create an element in my app and also apply `bg-green-800`. From now on both element and custom component show the correct background color.

Is there a way to use tailwindcss in a custom angular library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tailwind 3+ easy solution:
Just add your library folder to the `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
      "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
      "./projects/ui-components/src/**/*.{html,ts}",
    ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

Tested with Angular 13, works like a charm!

Comment: but when we run `ng build` the dist/project folder's CSS file does not include the built tailwindcss but rather the source tailwindcss. so basically it does not work. Bcs for library projects angular uses ng-packgr compiler which has postcss but does not load postcss config or is not extendible in any way that we can use of tailwind's postcss plugin.

Comment: You can actually get around the issue you are describing by changing the tailwind config on the project using your component:

```content: [
      "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
      "./node_modules/ui-components/**/*.{html,ts,js}",
    ],
```

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution for my own problem. One needs to create a static stylesheet file since it is not generated automatically.

- Create the tailwindcss.config.js in the root of your library
- From the root of the library run `npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build -o ./src/lib/tailwind.scss`
- Include the `tailwind.scss` file in your component: `styleUrls: ['../tailwind.scss']`. (Careful with the path)

One still needs to run the `npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build -o ./src/lib/tailwind.scss` everytime a new class is added to a component to be included into `tailwind.scss`.

Comment: I did that but the output file is 4MB (it contains all tailwind css), I'm wondering if I'm missing the "postcss" step after when doing this technique

Comment: This generated only the css that was used by the components: `npx tailwindcss -o ./src/lib/tailwind.scss`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but while trying to figure out how to do this, I found that adding Tailwind dependency to Angular libraries is basically not possible, as of the date of writing this answer. This is because `ng-packagr` does not support loading up a custom `postcss` config.

Find more details here:

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1471

https://github.com/ngneat/tailwind/issues/12

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/643

https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/1059 -> I found this to  be the best explanation as to why it is not possible.

The accepted answer, while works, will copy the whole TailwindCSS bundle into the final build, which defeats the purpose.

---

Update: [This is another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72208906/3640307) of adding TailwindCSS support to your Angular library, if you really need to do so. While, it's still a "hacky" way, but it is better than the accepted answer since it does not include the entire TailwindCSS stylesheet, thanks to @Charly

Comment: I answered another the same day :) -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72208906/9404093
Agreed there's no good way.

Comment: @Charly I just read your answer and find it better than the accepted answer, hence I have added it as a link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are consuming your library in the project of same directory, no specific action is needed. Just modify your tailwind.config.js file to contain html files of your library.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.html",
    "./projects/my-fancy-library/src/**/*.html", //just add this line
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

But if you are publishing the library to a npm registry, the previous approach could not work and your tailwind styles won't apply .For overcome this you can create a separate style.css file for your library (which will be generated by tailwind) and then import that style.css into your destination project, as you import Angular Material styles or any other libraries styles to your project.

So for doing this, create a separate tailwind config file for your library. Name it like mylib-tailwind.config.js and put the path of your library html files in it:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./projects/my-fancy-library/src/**/*.html"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Also your package.json file should be something like this:

```
  {
    "scripts": {
      "build-lib": "ng build my-fancy-lib",
      "build-tailwind": "tailwindcss -c ./mylib-tailwind.config.js -i ./src/tailwind-input-style.scss -o ./dist/my-fancy-lib/src/lib/my-lib-tailwind.css --minify"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "10.4.13",
      "postcss": "8.4.20",
      "tailwindcss": "3.2.4"
    }
  }
```

After building your library with Angular cli, just run build-tailwind script to generate output style of your project in dist folder.

Again after publishing your dist folder and installing your library, for applying tailwind generated style add it to your destination project from angular.json file.

Comment: hi thx for your approach, I just wonder how to call bundle those tailwind when development and after build and publishing packages into npm

I have and issue when I publish angular library to npm it loosing all tailwind class

Answer (score 0):

Your solution didn't work in my case **just because of the `npx tailwindcss-cli build` compiler**.

My solution is basically the same as yours, but using the `npx tailwindcss` compiler, like the [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production) suggest.

### Step 1

In your library folder, have the Tailwind config `content` as if the origin is the base project folder:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './projects/my-lib/**/*.{html,ts,css,scss}',
    './**/*.{html,ts,css,scss}', // optional
  ],
};
```

### Step 2

In step 3, a `tailwind.scss` file will be generated into the `my-lib/src/lib` folder, so (as suggested by [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67719065/11438282)) you have to *include the `tailwind.scss` file in your component:*

*`styleUrls: ['../tailwind.scss']`.*

*(Careful with the path)*.

### Step 3

Run this command (this is the app context, but it can be run from the library if the `content` in the `tailwind.config.js` has the optional path, and obv the paths have to be adapted).

```bash
npx tailwindcss@latest -c ./projects/my-lib/tailwind.config.js -o ./projects/my-lib/src/lib/tailwind.scss
```

Run it every time before building the library. This part must be run from the app context. `package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:my-lib": "npx tailwindcss@latest -c ./projects/my-lib/tailwind.config.js -o ./projects/my-lib/src/lib/tailwind.scss & ng build my-lib"
  }
}
```