How to use TailwindCSS with Angular Libraries
I have a Angular library who use TailwindCSS. This library has the theme with the plugins configured with components to shared with another microfrontends.
I export from the library all the components, the scss files (importing the tailwind base, utilities), vendors etc., also the theme.
Inside my microfrontend I import the config tailwind from the library, to use like a preset, but when I import a component from the library, which the path are not inside the content of tailwind.config.js, the CSS are not loaded and not applied.
This import is inside the angular App who consume the lib.
Here I import the tailwind config from the library,
but the components imported from the library, are not inside the content, so the Tailwind doesn't load the CSS for the component.
const tailwindConfig = require('./node_modules/frontend-commons/src/lib/tailwind/config')

module.exports = {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts,scss}'], <- Source off angular app not lib
    ...tailwindConfig
};


How I can fix it? The library and the app are not in the same workspace. They are different repositories.

You may find your answer in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67706691/using-tailwindcss-in-custom-angular-library?rq=2
